command not found: antlr4ng
I am trying to generate a parser using antlr4ng. I've already installed antlr4ng and antlr4ng-cli using npm install antlr4ng and npm install antlr4ng-cli. But when trying to execute antlr4ng -Dlanguage=TypeScript -o generated/ -visitor -listener -Xexact-output-dir path/to/YourLexer.g4 path/to/YourParser.g4 it says command not found: antlr4ng. I hope you have a solution for me.

Which version of antlr4ng did you use?

Can you report this issue in the antlr4ng issue tracker? This way we might be able to debug the problem.

running npm install -g antlr4ng-cli worked for me. But i don't understand the reason for it not working without installing it globally.

If it is installed without the -g option, then it is installed relative to the current directory in ./node_modules/.bin. When using a shell, a path environmental variable is used for determining where search for executables. Unless you specify that path where npm installed it, the shell won't find the installed script.
